# Is there any Android developer OS version available?

Tags: android, operating-system, version, android-source

I'm wondering if there's a possibility to have access to any of "developer version of the Android system" as the Android doc says? As you probably know some tools work on developer version only which is AFAIK available exclusively on emulator, which let's say *doesn't work well*.

If there would be such, I'd rather install it on one of my devices and could debug it there.

Would it be legal in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have one of the Google phone devices you can build your own type of the Android OS for your needs without problem. [Here](http://source.android.com/source/building.html) you can find instructions how to do this and how to upload your built OS on your device. For instance, to build development version for Galaxy Nexus you should run configuration command:

```
lunch full_maguro-eng
```

Comment: hmm, thanks for the info, but actually I need a tablet - Google does not have any yet. Would it be possible to install self-prepared OS on non-Google device without hacking it?

Comment: It is possible. All you need are proprietary drivers for your device. Then you can build the version for your device. In case of Google devices the process is easier. Take a look at the different ROMs for your device and try to find instructions how to install the ROM on your device. Then find the proprietary drivers, build your version and install your ROM according to the instructions.

Comment: OK, great, one last thing - are there any instructions what to do in order to enable all those developer-only features in my custom build? AFAIK they're most security issues. Is it called in some way? It would be simpler for me to search i. e. for such build.

Comment: I have not built versions for other then Google devices, but I guess you'll have to run command: lunch <your_platform>-eng